# Help to find closed form:$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2^n(n^{2k+1}+n^{2k}+n^{2k-1}+\cdots+ny+x)\over (n+1)(2n+1)(2n+3){2n\choose n}}=F(k)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

I am unable to find the general closed form and would appreciate if you can help me. Thank you.

$k\ge0$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2^n(n^{2k+1}+n^{2k}+n^{2k-1}+\cdots+ny+x)\over (n+1)(2n+1)(2n+3){2n\choose n}}=F(k)$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2^n(ny+x)\over (n+1)(2n+1)(2n+3){2n\choose n}}=F(0)$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2^n(n^3+n^2+ny+x)\over (n+1)(2n+1)(2n+3){2n\choose n}}=F(1)$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2^n(n^5+n^4+n^3+n^2+ny+x)\over (n+1)(2n+1)(2n+3){2n\choose n}}=F(2)$$

I only managed to work out the closed form for $k=0,1$ and $2$

$$F(0)=(x-y)\cdot{\pi^2\over 8}+(2x-3y)\cdot{\pi\over 2}-(4x-6y)$$

$$F(1)=(x-y)\cdot{\pi^2\over 8}+(2x-3y-3)\cdot{\pi\over 2}-(4x-6y-5)$$

$$F(2)=(x-y)\cdot{\pi^2\over 8}+(2x-3y-9)\cdot{\pi\over 2}-(4x-6y-18)$$

I found these using some algebra manipulation and trial and error via a sum calculator.

Comment: Have you tried working out $F(3)$?? The only difference between your terms $F(0)$, $F(1)$, and $F(2)$ appears to be a negative integer on the second term (appears to be a power of three) and a negative integer on the last term (I can't discern a pattern at this point).

Comment: You can of course find a pattern in all this... I would recommend splitting the fraction in your sum into two parts, one with variable degree polynomial numerator and a fixed, cubic denominator and leave the other fraction as $\frac{2^n}{{2n \choose n}}$ for a bit. Run polynomial long division on the first term.

Comment: Your terms appear to be of the form $F(k)=(x-y)\cdot{\pi^2\over 8}+(2x-3y-3^k)\cdot{\pi\over 2}-(4x-6y-c_k)$ though I can't discern $c_k$ without $F(3)$. If you can get $F(3)$ and conjecture the value of $c_k$ then induction will be your best friend. Otherwise, what you'll have to do will be a bit more tricky and a bit more trial and error.

Comment: For what it's worth, $\frac{\pi^2}{8}$ is the value of $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$. Not sure where your $\frac{\pi}{2}$ comes from quite yet... My guess is that you can turn the binomial coefficients into factorials and then convert to a Taylor series of a trig function about some value $x$, where the value of the trig function at $x$ is $\frac{\pi}{2}$. You might also be able to get a sum for it directly... Look up Leibez formula for Pi, as a related sum might come up here, and you could always convert your final answer into sums and try to combine the sums back into one to...

Comment: ... prove your answer in reverse. I'm unfortunately on mobile and lack any decent keyboard to type MathJax and I also don't have any paper around to work this out, so what I have above is more or less as far as I can go mentally. If you have any questions following my suggestions post a comment, and either I or someone else will hopefully get back to you as soon as possible

Comment: Ok, I will try and evaluate $F(3)$

Comment: $F(3)=(x-y)\cdot{\pi^2\over 8}+(2x-3y+18)\cdot{\pi\over 2}-(4x-6y-111)$

Comment: @BrevanELlefsen I don't think there is an obvious pattern for this.

Comment: you are correct. I take back what I said earlier... It looks like the first coefficient is $3T_k$ where $T_k$ are the triangle numbers. I can't even discern a patten in $c_k$, nor can the OEIS (Online Encyclopedia on Integer Sequences). Alright, you're going to have to expand that sucker. I think you can write it as a polynomial times a double factorial, though that has yet to be tested on paper. Follow with my suggestions above for now along with anything else you can think of and I'll try to attack the problem later today when I'm more available

Comment: $$ \begin{align} F(M)&=F(0)+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^n\left[(n^2+n^3)+(n^4+n^5)+\cdots+(n^{2M}+n^{2M+1})\right]}{{2n\choose n}(n+1)(2n+1)(2n+3)} \\ &=F(0)+\sum_{n=\color{red}{1}}^{\infty}\frac{2^n\left(n^2+n^4+\cdots+n^{2M}\right)}{{2n\choose n}(2n+1)(2n+3)} =F(0)+\sum_{k=1}^{M}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n\,n^{2k}}{{2n\choose n}(2n+1)(2n+3)} \\ &=F(0)+\frac12\sum_{k=1}^{M}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{2^n\,n^{2k}}{{2n\choose n}(2n+1)}-\frac{2^n\,n^{2k}}{{2n\choose n}(2n+3)}\right] \end{align} $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Partial Solution**

@HazemOrabi already covered most of this in his comment, but I'll try to expand the idea in his comment into a bit more into an answer.

You wrote

> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2^n(n^{2k+1}+n^{2k}+n^{2k-1}+\cdots+ny+x)\over (n+1)(2n+1)(2n+3){2n\choose n}}=F(M)$$

However, you are abusing summation notation in the numerator. You can't use middle dots to imply a continued sum when the last two terms are different. Also, the variable $k$ shows up in your sum for no reason. What I presume you mean (from reading your closed forms for fixed $M$) is that
$$F(M)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2^n[ny+x]+2^n[(n^{2M+1}+n^{2M})+\cdots+(n^5+n^4)+(n^3+n^2)]\over (n+1)(2n+1)(2n+3){2n\choose n}}$$
We can rewrite the numerator as
$$F(M)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2^n[ny+x]+2^n\sum_{k=1}^M (n^{2k}+n^{2k+1})\over (n+1)(2n+1)(2n+3){2n\choose n}}$$
We can split the two terms in the numerator, and we know that the first converges and is equal to $F(0)$
$$F(M)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2^n[ny+x] \over (n+1)(2n+1)(2n+3){2n\choose n}} +\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2^n\sum_{k=1}^M (n^{2k}+n^{2k+1})\over (n+1)(2n+1)(2n+3){2n\choose n}}$$
$$F(M)=F(0)+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2^n\sum_{k=1}^M (n^{2k}+n^{2k+1})\over (n+1)(2n+1)(2n+3){2n\choose n}}$$
When $n=0$ the sum is zero, so we change index
$$F(M)=F(0)+\sum_{n=\color{red}{1}}^{\infty}{2^n\sum_{k=1}^M (n^{2k}+n^{2k+1})\over (n+1)(2n+1)(2n+3){2n\choose n}}$$
We now bring the $(n+1)$ from the denominator into the sum in the numerator and do some canceling, noting that $n^{2k} + n^{2k+1} = n^{2k}(n+1)$
$$F(M)=F(0)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{2^n\sum_{k=1}^M (\frac{n^{2k}+n^{2k+1}}{n+1})\over (2n+1)(2n+3){2n\choose n}}=F(0)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{2^n\sum_{k=1}^M n^{2k}\over (2n+1)(2n+3){2n\choose n}}$$
We can now sum in a different order and thus pull the inner summation in the numerator to the outside. *If you don't trust me, try expanding the sum and grouping in different ways to get this result*
$$F(M)=F(0)+\sum_{k=1}^M\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{2^nn^{2k}\over (2n+1)(2n+3){2n\choose n}}$$
We now split the fraction into two using Partial Fraction Decomposition on $\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+3)}$
$$F(M)=F(0)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^M\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n\,n^{2k}}{{2n\choose n}}\left[\frac{1}{(2n+1)}-\frac{1}{(2n+3)}\right]$$
We now distribute and split the inner summation to get
$$F(M)=F(0)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^M\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n\,n^{2k}}{{2n\choose n}}\left[\frac{1}{(2n+1)}-\frac{1}{(2n+3)}\right]$$
$$F(M)=F(0)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^M\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n\,n^{2k}}{{2n\choose n}(2n+1)}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n\,n^{2k}}{{2n\choose n}(2n+3)}\right)$$
We now use the fact that ${2n \choose 2} = \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$
$$F(M)=F(0)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^M\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n\,n^{2k}(n!)^2}{(2n)!(2n+1)}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n\,n^{2k}(n!)^2}{(2n)!(2n+3)}\right)$$
$$F(M)=F(0)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^M\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n\,n^{2k}(n!)^2}{(2n)!(2n+1)}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n\,n^{2k}(n!)^2}{(2n)!(2n+3)}\right)$$
We now use the fact that $(2n-1)!! = \frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}$
$$F(M)=F(0)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^M\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n!)\,n^{2k}}{(2n-1)!!\,(2n+1)}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n!)\,n^{2k}}{(2n-1)!!\,(2n+3)}\right)$$
We can simplify the denominators a bit
$$F(M)=F(0)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^M\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n!)\,n^{2k}}{(2n+1)!!}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n!)\,n^{2k}\,(2n+1)}{(2n+3)!!\,}\right)$$
We can simplify the denominators a bit
$$F(M)=F(0)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^M\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n!)\,n^{2k}}{(2n+1)!!}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n!)\,n^{2k}\,(2n+1)}{(2n+3)!!\,}\right)$$
This appears similar to
$$\arcsin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2(2n+1)}x^{2n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!(2n+1)}x^{2n+1}$$
But I can't figure out how to solve from here

Comment: A second variation could be obtained if we exclude the first term (n=1) in order to use the identity: $$ \begin{align} n^{2M+2}-n^2 &= n^{2M+2} -n^{2M}+n^{2M} + \cdots -n^4+n^4 -n^2 = \left(n^2-1\right)\,\sum_{k=1}^{M}n^{2k} \\ &\Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{M}n^{2k} = \frac{n^{2M+2}-n^2}{n^2-1} = \frac{n^2\left(n^{2M}-1\right)}{n^2-1} \\ & \end{align} $$

Comment: $$ \begin{align} F(M) &=F(0)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n\left(n^2+n^4+\cdots+n^{2M}\right)}{{2n\choose n}(2n+1)(2n+3)} \\ &=F(0)+\frac{M}{15}+\sum_{n=\color{red}{2}}^{\infty}\frac{2^n\,n^2\left(n^{2M}-1\right)}{{2n\choose n}(n^2-1)(2n+1)(2n+3)} \\ &=F(0)+\frac{M}{15}-\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{2^n\,n^2}{{2n\choose n}(n^2-1)(2n+1)(2n+3)}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{2^n\,n^{2M+2}}{{2n\choose n}(n^2-1)(2n+1)(2n+3)} \\ &=F(0)+\frac{M}{15}-\left(\frac{3227}{900}-\frac{14\pi}{15}-\frac{\pi^2}{16}\right)+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{2^n\,n^{2(M+1)}}{{2n\choose n}(n^2-1)(2n+1)(2n+3)} \end{align} $$

Comment: @HazemOrabi interesting. I saw that approach, but I wasn't able to get the last couple steps and got stumped. You should absolutely flesh that out and post as an answer.

Comment: @HazemOrabi also, the best ideas I've gotten to finish the proof I've started are (1) to go back to the step where I converted the combination to factorials and instead use the integral form.. I should get a quadruple or quintic integral if things don't cancel beautifully though. (2) take the inner sums on my final step and solve for them.  I have a closed form for the exponential generating functions, but pulling the sum of out if it's EGF is proving... Difficult so far. I've only been able to prove the cases where $k=0,1,2,3$ that way so far...  I'll keep chipping at it though.

Comment: @HazemOrabi if you have any other ideas don't hesitate... I really don't like my solution outlines at the moment and am looking for a prettier and more interesting proof.

Comment: Thanks Brevan. As you mentioned, the last sum is related to $\arcsin$. So far, it can be expressed using a hypergeometric function ${_pF_q(a;b;\frac12)}$. I am hoping to find a better formula before posting an answer. Nevertheless, you did a good job. Happy Holidays (super)man.